# Filter select options based on previous selections

Tags: angularjs

I have a dynamic number of select options in AngularJS with a predefined list of values.

Essentially, when someone choose one value on the 1st select dropdown, I want to remove it from the rest of the dropdown lists.

```
<body ng-app="myNgApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="button" value="Add group" ng-if="availableGroups < allGroups.length" ng-click="addGroup()" />
    <input type="button" value="Remove group" ng-click="removeGroup()" />

    <div ng-repeat="group in [].constructor(availableGroups) track by $index">
      <select ng-model="selectedGroups_[$index]" ng-options="col for col in allGroups"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>


var ngApp = angular.module('myNgApp', []);

ngApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.allGroups = ['group 1', 'group 2', 'group 3', 'group 4', 'group 5'];
  $scope.availableGroups = 0;

  $scope.addGroup = function() {
    $scope.availableGroups += 1;
  }

  $scope.removeGroup = function($index) {
    $scope.availableGroups -= 1;
  }
  

});
```

You can find the [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/3tn1v78p/26/)

What I tried to do is to create an array `selectedOptions` and with an `ng-change`, push or remove the value to that array. Then use it to filter all `select` elements. However, the moment I push the value to the array, it is obviously removed from the one that got selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think while removing also your array needs to be updated right? by replacing the removed selected option, so I have implemented that too here you can check this code or else I will attach my jsfiddle link here [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sweetyDev123/86edLxq4/1/)

```js
var ngApp = angular.module('myNgApp', []);

ngApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.allGroups = ['group 1', 'group 2', 'group 3', 'group 4', 'group 5'];
  $scope.availableGroups = 0;
  $scope.selectedOptionsList = [];

  $scope.addGroup = function() {
    $scope.availableGroups += 1;
  };

  $scope.removeGroup = function() {
    $scope.availableGroups -= 1;
    $scope.selectedOptionsList.pop();
  };

  $scope.neededSelectableOptions = function(index) {
    var selectedValues = $scope.selectedOptionsList.filter(function(value, i) {
      return i !== index && value !== null && value !== undefined;
    });

    return $scope.allGroups.filter(function(group) {
      return !selectedValues.includes(group);
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myNgApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="button" value="Add group" ng-if="availableGroups < allGroups.length" ng-click="addGroup()" />
    <input type="button" value="Remove group" ng-click="removeGroup()" />

    <div ng-repeat="group in [].constructor(availableGroups) track by $index">
      <select ng-model="selectedOptionsList[$index]" ng-options="col for col in neededSelectableOptions($index)"></select>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```